# Getting the JSON values in a component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component, json, chatter-api

[image]I have a chatter API response in below JSON format

```
    "currentPageToken": null,
"currentPageUrl": "/services/data/v39.0/chatter/feeds/record/0F98E0000004UhASAU/feed-elements",
"elements": [
    {
        "body": {
            "isRichText": false,
            "messageSegments": [
                {
                    "text": "Hi All,\n\nPlease find attached the THOR February Release notes. Please refer to the deck to know about the enhancements which have been deployed.
                    "type": "Text"
                }]
```

I want the "text" part shown in the component. The JSON value i had parsed to an object. Its not throwing any warnings/error but does not show any values in the UI.

```
          Component
         ===========
        <aura:component  access="global" controller="ChatterFeedController">
        <aura:attribute name = "groupatt" type="Object" /> 
        <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.userFeedItem}" value="{!this}"/> 

       <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped">
          <tbody>
              <aura:iteration items="{!v.groupatt}" var="att">
                <tr>
                <td>{!att}</td>
                </tr>
              </aura:iteration>
         </tbody>
      </table>

     Controller
     ==========
    userFeedItem: function(component, event, helper) {
    var userFeed = component.get("c.getFeedData");
    var groupID = component.get("v.groupattid");
    console.log("GroupID: " + groupID);
    userFeed.setParams({"groupId" : groupID});
    userFeed.setCallback(this,function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
        if(state==="SUCCESS"){
           var jtext = response.getReturnValue();  
       for (var i=0; i<jtext.elements.length; ++i){
          var body = jtext.elements[i].body;
       }
        component.set("v.groupatt",body.messageSegments[0].text);
        } else {
            console.log('Problem getting feed, response state: ' + state);
        }    
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(userFeed);
},
```

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: Thanks @Caspar. It worked very well. But another issue that cropped up now is that since I have to deal with a lot of JSON content and  I have put a for loop condition inside the trigger to filter out only the text area (Have updated the code above). But it seems the call back is failing.

Comment: Says Cannot read property "text" of Undefined.

Comment: You need to check if messageSegments contains anything. Something like this: `if (body && body.messageSegments.length){component.set("v.groupatt",body.messageSegments[0].text);}

Comment: Worked again :). Also, now instead of displaying each posts, its coming like the image above. Each letter in each row. Any thoughts what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: You have a problem with scope - your body variable won't be visible outside the for loop. I'm fixing it...

Comment: Ok added sample callback handler - take a look at the end of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57211/discussion-between-caspar-harmer-and-bijil-ravindran).

Comment: Thanks for all your help.. I indeed sorted out everything I require now.

Comment: If this helped you, you can mark it as accepted. That way others will know that the answer is a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method that takes the output that you have in your question and parses and extracts the required data.

I noticed that you have some problems with the output JSON - however, this is just an output from chatter correct - so I doubt there is a problem there - perhaps just a transcription error?

Here is the sample method that you can drop into any component:

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        var jsonOBJ = {
                    "currentPageToken": null,
                    "currentPageUrl": "/services/data/v39.0/chatter/feeds/record/0F98E0000004UhASAU/feed-elements",
                    "elements": [
                      {
                        "body": {
                          "isRichText": false,
                          "messageSegments": [
                            {
                              "text": "Hi All,\n\nPlease find attached the THOR February Release notes. Please refer to the deck to know about the enhancements which have been deployed.",
                              "type": "Text"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  };
        var jsonSTR = JSON.stringify(jsonOBJ);
        var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(jsonSTR);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonOBJ));
        console.log(jsonOBJ.elements[0].body.messageSegments[0].text);
    }
})
```

If the object you are receiving is actually an object there is no need to parse or stringify - try something like this:

```
var jsonResult = response.getReturnValue();
//breaking this into two lines because so formatting doesn't like it:
var body = jsonResult.elements[0].body;
component.set("v.groupatt",body.messageSegments[0].text);
```

**EDIT - Added a sample callback handler**

```
userFeed.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        var jtext = response.getReturnValue();
        var groupatt = component.get("v.groupatt");

        for (var i = 0; i < jtext.elements.length; ++i) {
            var body = jtext.elements[i].body;
                if (body && body.messageSegments.length){
                    groupatt.push(body.messageSegments[0].text);
                }
        }
        component.set("v.groupatt", strArray);
    } 
    else {
        console.log('Problem getting feed, response state: ' + state);
    }
});
```

And finally, for the component itself change from object to string array:

```
<aura:attribute name = "groupatt" type="String[]" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned that the response from the chatter apex class response.getReturnValue() is itself an object type. However, not able to display the "text" in the component if I set the component with this value. I tried stringfying and then parsing it again but to no luck. I can get the values in the console but to show it in the UI is the challenge for me.

Comment: Remove the last two params from your stringify method.

Comment: In your component, make and outputText or something and bind it to the actual text you want. You can't bind it to an object, you need to bind it to a PROPERTY of the object